# UIScrollView has an unexplainable position in UITabBarController with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

Using Xcode to create a new project, a Tabbed Application.

On the first view controller I add a UIScrollView, bind it to the view for all borders. Then I add a UIView "Content View" with equal width as the superview of the UIScrollView. I add a label on the top and a label on the bottom of the content view, and make sure that the size of the content view amounts to a higher height than the height of the scroll view, so that we get a scroll.

[image: auto layout setup]

Still I get a horizontal scroll bar in the view. Why? The width of the content view is bound to the width of the superview of the scroll view, which should thus be as wide as the device, and give no scroll. What am I missing?

The project is [downloadable from here](http://dsh.re/048b1) if you want to play with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two constraints for the ScrollView which are set relative to the margin.

If you make the leading and trailing constraints relative to the superview with no margin then your code works as you require with no horizontal scroll bar.